Why is Gavin listed twice on the “Top Beta Users” list?
The Top Beta Users List shows gavinandresen twice.
Is this a bug?  I asked this in area51 but maybe this meta site is a better place for it.


You just wanted to show us that you're in the top spot, right? ;) As for your question, I have no idea. Looks like a bug to me.

Looks like a bug, the SE folks are looking into it.

This has been addressed on your Area51 Discussion question.

@David - shouldn't someone post an answer on this? It's funny having it as status-completed, but with no accepted, upvoted ... or any answer.

@ripper234 Well, it looks like Emmett did answer it over at Area 51 but I'll copy/paste his answer here for completion's sake.

Emmett answered this over at Area 51:

A bug caused 65 users to be doubly listed in various Top Beta Users
  lists in Area 51. It's been fixed, and the duplicate entries have been
  removed, so gavinandresen only shows up once now.


It's happening again. I'm in the #1 spot twice, look: i42.tinypic.com/nzpqtd.png
